# How a real life docker project usually works?

Tags: docker

I'm studying docker for 2 days now. I've understood containers, images and volumes basic concepts, but after some searching I still don't understood how is the correct usage of the docker in a project. I know that it depends from project to project, but what is the most usual case?

Let's supose that we have a node project using some libraries. A commom project would store the node image in a docker container, and the source code would be stored on github? Other developers will have to install the dependencie when they pull the project or it is suposed to send node_modules to docker hub somehow?

Comment: i think you should read more documents/blogs/tutorials. maybe it's a little hard to understand the docker user cases, for a programmer who never been involved in team work/automated testing/deployments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Docker (or more specifically Docker project) as a set of instructions that will build the image and run it in a container, along with your code.

As such, you want to store that set of instruction in a git repository (i.e. github) so when a collaborator pulls the repo they can run it and expect the same result.

Picture this metaphore: imagine Docker is IKEA.

You order a wardrobe from them and they bring it to your house (git pull).
You receive all the pieces plus the manual.

When you start to follow the steps in the manual - this is like running "docker build". For this specific wardrobe you might need your own hammer or a screwdriver - this is the base image (FROM directive) - a bare minimum needed to build the image. Finally, when you put all the pieces together and you can place your wardrobe in desired spot - that is like running the container.

In this world, your github repo is simply the box stored at some IKEA warehouse. Now, anyone buying the wardrobe and following the manual should expect to see the same product, working the same way. Meaning, an application behaving exactly the same way regardless of where it was set up.

This is the whole point of dockerizing your projects.